# How can I implement a lazy-evaluated stateful class with internal dependencies in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm writing a financial calculation class which will have a number of setter function inputs, some private intermediate values and a number of getter functions as outputs.

- The private intermediate values are only dependant on the input values.
- The output values (accessed by public getters) are only dependant on the inputs and the intermediate values.

Ultimately you could draw the whole thing as a somewhat tangled acyclic directed graph whith a bunch of inputs on one side, eventually flowing to a bunch of outputs on the right hand side.

What's the best way to implement this class. I have some spesific requirements:

- Where possible, lazy evaluate. When an input changes we have now way of knowing what outputs might be required.
- The class has to be easy to re-design, so some kind of declarative model would epreferred.

Ideally I'd like to be able to say that C depends on A and B. If C were requested after either A or B had changed then it would know tht C needed to be re-calculated, otherwise C would never need to be refreshed.

IIs there a Java pattern that might help me cleanly implement this kind of calculator?

Comment: Something like this: Hold input in an unspecific container, if one getter is called create a Strategy-Object based on the given input and the intermediate values and let calculate the SO object the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a solution by creating a future value that is recalculable.

```
public class Computation<T> {
   private T value;
   private Set<Computation<?>> usedBy;

   public T getValue(Computation<?> getter) {
     if (usedBy == null) {
       // value was not computed
       value = compute();
       usedBy = new HashSet();
     }
     if (getter != null) {
       // add a dependency
       usedBy.add(getter);
     }
     return value;
   }

   protected T compute() {
     // override when needed a lazily-computed value
     return null;
   }

   public void setValue(T value) {
     // invalidate this value
     invalidate();
     // set the new value
     this.value = value;
     usedBy = new HashSet();
   }

   public void invalidate() {
     if (usedBy != null) {
       for (Computation<?> c : usedBy) {
         c.invalidate();
       }
       usedBy = null;
     }
     value = null;
   }
}

public class Business {
  private Computation<Integer> a = new Computation<Integer>();
  private Computation<Integer> b = new Computation<Integer>();
  private Computation<Integer> c = new Computation<Integer>() {
    public Integer compute() {
      return a.getValue(this) + b.getValue(this);
    }
  };

  public void setA(int v) {
    a.setValue(v);
  }
  public void setB(int v) {
    b.setValue(v);
  }
  public int getC() {
    return c.getValue(null);
  }
}
```

It is completely lazy and figures out the dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm after!

Comment: A question about the syntax here: In the statement where we define class-member c - this statement seems to define a member and simoltaneously override a method in the class - I've never seen this syntax before. Does this technique have a name, and can you point me to something in the language reference where I can read more?

Comment: It is an anonymous class.
More info: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pattern like this.

```
double[] inputs = { ... }
double[] previousInputs = { Double.NaN, etc }; // NaN is never equal.
double[] outputs = 

public void update() {
   if (!Arrays.equals(inputs, previousInputs)) {
       recalculate(inputs, outputs);
       copyTo(inputs, previousInputs);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works and I've got something similar to that already (using nulls instead of NaNs) - but it's not declarative. That's a very imperative way of doing it, dont you think?

Comment: That is true.  Sometimes the simplest approach is best.  You could make it more declarative, but I would try to avoid making it more complex in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have some sort of real-time stream processing problem.

Take a look at twitter [storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm). Even if you decide not to use it you can borrow some concepts explained at [tutorial page](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial).

Comment: This technology is amazing, and if the project were scaled-up the kind of thing I would want. Is this technology actually used by Twitter somewhere in their system?

Comment: Yes it currently used at twitter to keep statistics on user clicks for every URL and domain. This video presentation http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Storm should be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I agree with Peter but for arguments sake I have two other answers.  I would recommend looking at a rules engine (e.g. Drools) for implementing flexible business logic like this.  They are designed so that the rules for updates between variables are easy to set and change at will.  They should also be fairly performant.

Then, for the DYI-er, here is a Spring inspired version.  The biggest drawback is that you get your dependencies as a list.  You could easily use a HashMap but then you'd lose your syntax-safety.

```
public abstract class Variable<T> {

  private T currentValue;
  private List<Variable<?>> dependencies = new ArrayList<Variable<?>>();
  private List<Variable<?>> upstream = new ArrayList<Variable<?>>();

  public T get() {
    return currentValue;
  }

      public void set(T newValue) {
    currentValue = newValue;
    updateUpstream();
  }

  public abstract T recalculateValue(List<Variable<?>> dependencies);

  private void update() {
    set(recalculateValue());
  }

  private void updateUpstream() {
    for(Variable<?> variable : upstream) {
      variable.update();
    }
  }

  private void addUpstream(Variable<?> variable) {
    upstream.add(variable);
  }

  public void setDependencies(List<Variable<?>> dependencies) {
    this.dependencies = dependencies;
    for(Variable<?> variable) {
      variable.addUpstream(this);
    }
  }

}
```

The corresponding applicationContext.xml would look like:

```
<bean id="A" class="com.app.AVariable"/>
<bean id="B" class="com.app.BVariable"/>
<bean id="C" class="com.app.CVariable">
  <property name="dependencies">
    <list>
      <ref bean="A"/>
      <ref bean="B"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

For extra credit you could implement a bean post-processor to calculate and set the dependencies automatically based on annotations.  For example:

```
public class CVariable extends Variable<Integer> {
  private AVariable a;
  private BVariable b;

  @Dependency
  public void setA(AVariable a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  @Dependency
  public void setB(BVariable b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  //If you were going this route you wouldn't need the list of dependencies
  public Integer recalculateValue() {
    return a.get() + b.get();
  }

}
```